# How to login with Google on a xamarin App?

Tags: oauth, xamarin, oauth-2.0, google-plus

Im attempting to use the login with google ability in my xamarin app.
I got the twitter and facebook to work. I have google play services installed in my mobile.Droid project.

I created my app on google console. I have a client id and client secret.

How does the code change from twitters below? Is it a complete different process?

I have my button to open google "sign in" in my 
Mobile.portable project.

```
 public void Login(Action<Mobile.Twitter.Account> twitterLoginCompleted, Action twitterLoginFailed)
    {
        var auth = new OAuth1Authenticator(
           consumerKey: "Mykey_asdf",
                consumerSecret: "consumerSecret",
                requestTokenUrl: new Uri("https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token"),
                authorizeUrl: new Uri("https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize"),
                accessTokenUrl: new Uri("https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token"),
                callbackUrl: new Uri("https://mobile.twitter.com/home")

             );
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Register in google developer console as webapplication instead of installed application(android)* provide the redirect url with valid url ("http://abcd.com/xyz.aspx") same should be used in the application code.
2. On authentication complete it will return access_token
3. By using the access_token make the REST request to get user complete information (https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?access_token=" + accessTokenValue + “.)
4. Deserialize the json response to get information in object.

> If we registered in developer console as installed application(like
>   android) after making OAuth2Authenticator request it will show window
>   with message  **please copy this code switch to your application and
>   paste it there [code]** manually need to close the window and proceed
>   to authentication. to get ride of this webapplication type is choosen.

---

Refer for more info. :

- [Login by google account integration for Xamarin.Android and Xamarin.iOS](http://www.appliedcodelog.com/2015/08/login-by-google-account-integration-for.html)
- [Mobile authentication with Xamarin.Auth and refresh tokens](https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2014/11/13/mobile-authentication-with-xamarin-auth-and-refresh-tokens/)

Comment: When i setup the oaufh credentials for Android in the Google developers console there is no option for a redirect utl.  Simply a bundle identifier and the keystore key.   Using the xamarin. Auth i can get the the account login and permissions view see thebsxope and click accept.  My problem is at thisnstage it does not call my completed method or return to my app i am simply takes to a google home pacge.  Any ideas please?